# Ошибка при запросе к Яндекс API

Tags: php, get, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

При попытке GET запроса на url https://api-developer.tech.yandex.net/projects для определения идентификатора проекта получаю ответ:

> {"message": "You don't have the permission to access the requested
> resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."}

Хотя согласно документации должно работать:

В настоящее время у кабинета разработчика Яндекса есть свой API.

В его документации написано, как узнать лимиты API и количество выполненных запросов.

Для запроса нужно подготовить входные данные:

- Подключить API Кабинета разработчика и получить X-Auth-Key.
- Определить идентификатор проекта.
- Определить идентификатор сервиса.
- Теперь чтобы посмотреть параметры лимита запросов к API сервисов, используйте HTTP-запрос с методом GET:

  GET /projects/<project_id>/services/<service_id>/limits
  Host:  https://api-developer.tech.yandex.net
  X-Auth-Key:  <ключ API Кабинета разработчика>

Ответ вернёт как суточный лимит "limit", так и количество выполненных запросов "value". Определить остаток будет несложно. =)

Пробовал разные варианты, код запроса примерно такой:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-developer.tech.yandex.net/projects');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Host: https://api-developer.tech.yandex.net",
    "X-Auth-Key: b0017051-0b1e-4b09-9599-19f7a33ce"
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo ($response);
```

Из токена только убрал несколько символов, ответ получаю следующий:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN Content-Length: 137 Content-Type: application/json {"message":"You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."}
```

Comment: А каким образом вы делаете GET запрос, Приведите фрагмент кода, пожалуйста. Хотя очень похоже что вы не передаете X-Auth-Key

Comment: Пробовал разные варианты, но вот примерно такой: 

$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-developer.tech.yandex.net/projects');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "X-Auth-Key: b0017051-0b1e-4b09-9599-19f7a33ce"
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo ($response);